# Count the number of possible drawings

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Take a square, ABCD. Add two points, E and F on AB such that AE=EF=FB. Now, add G, H on BC, I and J on CD, K and L on AD.

Now pick four pairs of the eight points, E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L. Draw the line segments between your picks, for example EG,FH, IL, JK. If we consider two such drawings equal if they can be rotated into each other, how many different drawings are there? What if we mandate that the drawing must have a line of symmetry?

Comment: Can a pair consist of two points on the same side?

Comment: yes, that's totally legal.

Comment: This is a small finite problem so it can be solved by a computer program or checking cases by hand. Are you actually interested in some more general problem?

Comment: I am interested in the problem solving methodology of how you manually enumerate this correctly.

Comment: BTW this is basically asking whether the board game Tsuro has all the possible tiles. Surprisingly, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by arranging all the possible pairs in the following form:

\begin{pmatrix}
        \text{EF} & \text{EG} & \text{EH} & \text{EI} & \text{EJ} & \text{EK} & \text{EL} \\
         & \text{FG} & \text{FH}& \text{FI}& \text{FJ}& \text{FK}& \text{FL} \\
        && \text{GH}& \text{GI}& \text{GJ}& \text{GK}& \text{GL} \\
        &&& \text{HI}& \text{HJ}& \text{HK}& \text{HL}\\&&&& \text{IJ}& \text{IK}& \text{IL}\\&&&&& \text{JK}& \text{JL}\\&&&&&& \text{KL}\end{pmatrix}

Now we see that the number of pairing arrangements so that all $4$ pairs contain uncommon elements is $7\times 5\times 3\times 1=105$. Hence there must be $105$ such drawings. Notice that a drawing can be rotated to produce another pair drawing pattern from the other $104$ drawings if it is not symmetric about either the vertical (passing from the midpoints of $LK$ and $GH$) and horizontal (passing from the midpoints of $EF$ and $IJ$) axes, or the diagonal axes (lines $AC$ and $BD$). Also, a drawing can be rotated to produce 3 other drawing pattern from the other $104$ drawings if it is not symmetric about both the vertical (passing from the midpoints of $LK$ and $GH$) and horizontal (passing from the midpoints of $EF$ and $IJ$) axes, and the diagonal axes (lines $AC$ and $BD$).

Let us define **diagonalizing** as the process of rotating a drawing by $\pm45^\text{o}$ such that each node point is moved one unit forward (e.g. for $+45^\text{o}$ rotation, point $E$ becomes point $L$, $L$ becomes $K$, $K$ becomes $J$ and so on).

[image]

Notice that generally $\text{|EF|}\ne\text{|EL|}$, however *diagonalizing* allows a stretch or shrinkage for compensation.

I didn't know which of the cases you referred to so I listed all of them.

[image]

So if diagonalization and mirroring are not allowed then there are $35$ distinct drawings.

If diagonalization is allowed while mirroring is not, then there are $19$ distinct drawings.

If both diagonalization and mirroring are allowed, then there are $17$ distinct drawings.

Comment: Just curious--how did you make all the drawings?

Comment: List all the possible $105$ pairings in C++ and rotate each $4$ times to check whether they overlap. If they do, assimilate them. Finally list all the assimilated pairs and print them. And draw the diagrams corresponding to those pair-combinations on a software, say, MS-Paint. :D

Comment: wow.  That sounds like a lot of work. :D

Comment: care to publish the C++ source :) ? thanks for all the work!